How to copy all the child elements using new namespace prefix using xslt 1.0
My goal is to achieve a output xml where initial first 2 nodes have namespace as below.
<tp:Revision>2.0.10</tp:Revision>
<tp:Header>
and from message and all of its child nodes have namespace prefix as header:elementname.
Below is my input xml :
<DataPDU xmlns="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
    <Revision>2.0.10</Revision>
    <Header>
        <Message>
            <SenderReference>112712406</SenderReference>
            <MessageIdentifier>pacs.008.001.08</MessageIdentifier>
            <Format>MX</Format>
            <SubFormat>Input</SubFormat>
            <Sender>
                <DN>ou=xxx,o=ctbaau2s,o=swift</DN>
                <FullName>
                    <X1>CTBAAU2SFXD</X1>
                </FullName>
            </Sender>
            <Receiver>
                <DN>ou=xxx,o=testcsns,o=swift</DN>
                <FullName>
                    <X1>TESTCSNSSFXXX</X1>
                </FullName>
            </Receiver>
            <InterfaceInfo>
                <UserReference>M13782445</UserReference>
            </InterfaceInfo>
            <NetworkInfo>
                <SWIFTNetNetworkInfo>
                    <RequestType>pacs.008.001.08</RequestType>
                    <RequestSubtype>swift.cbprplus.02</RequestSubtype>
                </SWIFTNetNetworkInfo>
            </NetworkInfo>
        </Message>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
            <Fr>
                <FIId>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BICFI>CTBAAU2SFXD</BICFI>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </FIId>
            </Fr>
            <To>
                <FIId>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BICFI>TESTCSNSSFXXX</BICFI>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </FIId>
            </To>
            <BizMsgIdr>M13782445</BizMsgIdr>
            <MsgDefIdr>pacs.008.001.08</MsgDefIdr>
            <BizSvc>swift.cbprplus.02</BizSvc>
            <CreDt>2024-07-03T20:43:32+10:00</CreDt>
        </AppHdr>
        <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
            <FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
                <GrpHdr>
                    <MsgId>M13782445</MsgId>
                    <CreDtTm>2024-07-03T20:43:32+10:00</CreDtTm>
                    <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
                    <SttlmInf>
                        <SttlmMtd>INDA</SttlmMtd>
                    </SttlmInf>
                </GrpHdr>
                <CdtTrfTxInf>
                    <PmtId>
                        <InstrId>M13782445</InstrId>
                        <EndToEndId>M13782445</EndToEndId>
                        <UETR>a3d0dc5e-1b14-4e21-b431-8cf64396a978</UETR>
                    </PmtId>
                    <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="CHF">50004166.67</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
                    <IntrBkSttlmDt>2024-04-12</IntrBkSttlmDt>
                    <ChrgBr>abc</ChrgBr>
                    <InstgAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BICFI>CTBAAU2SFXD</BICFI>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </InstgAgt>
                    <InstdAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BICFI>TESTCSNSSFXXX</BICFI>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </InstdAgt>
                    <IntrmyAgt1>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BICFI>TESTSWINT33</BICFI>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </IntrmyAgt1>
                    <IntrmyAgt2>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BICFI>TESTSWINT22</BICFI>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </IntrmyAgt2>
                    <Dbtr>
                        <Id>
                            <OrgId>
                                <AnyBIC>CTBAAU2SFXD</AnyBIC>
                            </OrgId>
                        </Id>
                    </Dbtr>
                    <DbtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BICFI>TESTCSNSSFXXX</BICFI>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </DbtrAgt>
                    <CdtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BICFI>TESTSWINT11</BICFI>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </CdtrAgt>
                    <Cdtr>
                        <Id>
                            <OrgId>
                                <AnyBIC>TESTSWTBEN1</AnyBIC>
                            </OrgId>
                        </Id>
                    </Cdtr>
                    <InstrForCdtrAgt>
                        <Cd>codcdtr1</Cd>
                        <InstrInf>intfcdtr1</InstrInf>
                    </InstrForCdtrAgt>
                    <InstrForNxtAgt>
                        <InstrInf>infnxt1</InstrInf>
                    </InstrForNxtAgt>
                </CdtTrfTxInf>
            </FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
        </Document>
    </Body>
</DataPDU>

Below is my target output xml :
<DataPDU xmlns="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" xmlns:tp="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" xmlns:head="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.04" xmlns:header="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:header.001.001.04" xmlns:pacs="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.12">
    <tp:Revision>2.0.10</tp:Revision>
    <tp:Header>
        <header:Message>
            <header:SenderReference>112712406</header:SenderReference>
            <header:MessageIdentifier>pacs.008.001.08</header:MessageIdentifier>
            <header:Format>MX</header:Format>
            <header:SubFormat>Input</header:SubFormat>
            <header:Sender>
                <header:DN>ou=xxx,o=ctbaau2s,o=swift</header:DN>
                <header:FullName>
                    <header:X1>CTBAAU2SFXD</header:X1>
                </header:FullName>
            </header:Sender>
            <header:Receiver>
                <header:DN>ou=xxx,o=testcsns,o=swift</header:DN>
                <header:FullName>
                    <header:X1>TESTCSNSSFX</header:X1>
                </header:FullName>
            </header:Receiver>
            <header:InterfaceInfo>
                <header:UserReference>M13782445</header:UserReference>
            </header:InterfaceInfo>
            <header:NetworkInfo>
                <header:SWIFTNetNetworkInfo>
                    <header:RequestType>pacs.008.001.08</header:RequestType>
                    <header:RequestSubtype>swift.cbprplus.02</header:RequestSubtype>
                </header:SWIFTNetNetworkInfo>
            </header:NetworkInfo>
        </header:Message>
    </tp:Header>
</DataPDU>

Below is my XSLT :
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:main="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0" xmlns="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" xmlns:tp="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" xmlns:head="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.04" xmlns:header="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:header.001.001.04" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <DataPDU>
      <tp:Revision>
        <xsl:value-of select="/main:DataPDU/main:Header/main:Message/main:MessageIdentifier" />
      </tp:Revision>
      <tp:Header>
        <!--
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/main:DataPDU/main:Header/main:Message" />
          -->
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </tp:Header>
    </DataPDU>
  </xsl:template>
  
   <xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::main:Message]">
    <xsl:element name="header:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

This is still produces wrong output as below. Did a lot of research still struggling to figure out how to do this.
Wrong output :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataPDU xmlns="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" xmlns:header="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:header.001.001.04" xmlns:head="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.04" xmlns:tp="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" xmlns:main="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
    <tp:Revision>pacs.008.001.08</tp:Revision>
    <tp:Header>
        <DataPDU xmlns="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
            <Revision>2.0.10</Revision>
            <Header>
                <header:Message>
                    <header:SenderReference>112712406</header:SenderReference>
                    <header:MessageIdentifier>pacs.008.001.08</header:MessageIdentifier>
                    <header:Format>MX</header:Format>
                    <header:SubFormat>Input</header:SubFormat>
                    <header:Sender>
                        <header:DN>ou=xxx,o=ctbaau2s,o=swift</header:DN>
                        <header:FullName>
                            <header:X1>CTBAAU2SFXD</header:X1>
                        </header:FullName>
                    </header:Sender>
                    <header:Receiver>
                        <header:DN>ou=xxx,o=testcsns,o=swift</header:DN>
                        <header:FullName>
                            <header:X1>TESTCSNSSFXXX</header:X1>
                        </header:FullName>
                    </header:Receiver>
                    <header:InterfaceInfo>
                        <header:UserReference>M13782445</header:UserReference>
                    </header:InterfaceInfo>
                    <header:NetworkInfo>
                        <header:SWIFTNetNetworkInfo>
                            <header:RequestType>pacs.008.001.08</header:RequestType>
                            <header:RequestSubtype>swift.cbprplus.02</header:RequestSubtype>
                        </header:SWIFTNetNetworkInfo>
                    </header:NetworkInfo>
                </header:Message>
            </Header>
            <Body>
                <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
                    <Fr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
                        <FIId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
                            <FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
                                <BICFI xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">CTBAAU2SFXD</BICFI>
                            </FinInstnId>
                        </FIId>
                    </Fr>
                    <To xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
                        <FIId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
                            <FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
                                <BICFI xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">TESTCSNSSFXXX</BICFI>
                            </FinInstnId>
                        </FIId>
                    </To>
                    <BizMsgIdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">M13782445</BizMsgIdr>
                    <MsgDefIdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">pacs.008.001.08</MsgDefIdr>
                    <BizSvc xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">swift.cbprplus.02</BizSvc>
                    <CreDt xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">2024-07-03T20:43:32+10:00</CreDt>
                </AppHdr>
                <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                    <FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                        <GrpHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                            <MsgId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">M13782445</MsgId>
                            <CreDtTm xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">2024-07-03T20:43:32+10:00</CreDtTm>
                            <NbOfTxs xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">1</NbOfTxs>
                            <SttlmInf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                <SttlmMtd xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">INDA</SttlmMtd>
                            </SttlmInf>
                        </GrpHdr>
                        <CdtTrfTxInf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                            <PmtId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                <InstrId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">M13782445</InstrId>
                                <EndToEndId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">M13782445</EndToEndId>
                                <UETR xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">a3d0dc5e-1b14-4e21-b431-8cf64396a978</UETR>
                            </PmtId>
                            <IntrBkSttlmAmt xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08" Ccy="CHF">50004166.67</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
                            <IntrBkSttlmDt xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">2024-04-12</IntrBkSttlmDt>
                            <ChrgBr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">abc</ChrgBr>
                            <InstgAgt xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                <FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                    <BICFI xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">CTBAAU2SFXD</BICFI>
                                </FinInstnId>
                            </InstgAgt>
                            <InstdAgt xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                <FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                    <BICFI xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">TESTCSNSSFXXX</BICFI>
                                </FinInstnId>
                            </InstdAgt>
                            <IntrmyAgt1 xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                <FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                    <BICFI xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">TESTSWINT33</BICFI>
                                </FinInstnId>
                            </IntrmyAgt1>
                            <IntrmyAgt2 xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                <FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                    <BICFI xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">TESTSWINT22</BICFI>
                                </FinInstnId>
                            </IntrmyAgt2>
                            <Dbtr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                <Id xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                    <OrgId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                        <AnyBIC xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">CTBAAU2SFXD</AnyBIC>
                                    </OrgId>
                                </Id>
                            </Dbtr>
                            <DbtrAgt xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                <FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                    <BICFI xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">TESTCSNSSFXXX</BICFI>
                                </FinInstnId>
                            </DbtrAgt>
                            <CdtrAgt xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                <FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                    <BICFI xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">TESTSWINT11</BICFI>
                                </FinInstnId>
                            </CdtrAgt>
                            <Cdtr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                <Id xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                    <OrgId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                        <AnyBIC xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">TESTSWTBEN1</AnyBIC>
                                    </OrgId>
                                </Id>
                            </Cdtr>
                            <InstrForCdtrAgt xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                <Cd xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">codcdtr1</Cd>
                                <InstrInf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">intfcdtr1</InstrInf>
                            </InstrForCdtrAgt>
                            <InstrForNxtAgt xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
                                <InstrInf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">infnxt1</InstrInf>
                            </InstrForNxtAgt>
                        </CdtTrfTxInf>
                    </FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
                </Document>
            </Body>
        </DataPDU>
    </tp:Header>
</DataPDU>


Is there a reason why you want to make http://www.tutorialspoint.com the default namespace for the document and also bind it to the tp prefix?

I need to validate this whole document with one xsd file. Each part of the document refers to different namespace. As i have one xsd to validate i need to have one namespace which refers to whole document. Therefore i selected tp as the main test namespace that refer to whole document. If you have any better suggestions. I am happy to hear.

The tp prefix is bound to the http://www.tutorialspoint.com namespace URI, but there are other elements which belong to the urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:header.001.001.04 namespace, so your XSD schema will not validate the entire document. You will need multiple schemas to validate a document with multiple namespaces, I believe.

But my question was really about why you would make http://www.tutorialspoint.com the default namespace and also associate it with the tp prefix. In your schema, your validation rules are associated with a 'target' namespace URI http://www.tutorialspoint.com, so it doesn't matter what prefix your elements use, so long as they belong to that namespace URI. If you've made http://www.tutorialspoint.com the default namespace then you don't need to use the tp prefix for elements in that namespace.

This question was just a portion of what i wanted to achieve. I am using a wrapper xsd to validate the entire xml. Each section of the xml like..Body,document,Header has a different xsd file to validate that section and each of these xsd files have different namespace and i need to have one default namespace for the wrapper xsd as well which refer to the entire xml. So when i parse the xml using wrapper xsd i need to have one default namespace which refer to the entire xml.

I think the output you want could be produced simply by:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:main="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0"
xmlns:tp="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" 
xmlns:header="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:header.001.001.04" 
xmlns="http://www.tutorialspoint.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="main">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/main:DataPDU">
    <DataPDU>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="main:Revision | main:Header"/>
    </DataPDU>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="main:Revision | main:Header">
    <xsl:element name="tp:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="main:*">
    <xsl:element name="header:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

I have left out these namespace declarations because I don't see them being used anywhere:
xmlns:head="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.04"  
xmlns:pacs="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.12"

But if you want, you can add them to the namespaces declared in the xsl:stylesheet start tag and they will be copied to the output.

Probably one more disabling template is missing to match the desired output: <xsl:template match="main:Body"/>

@YitzhakKhabinsky In what way is my output different from the desired output (other than the two redundant namespaces)?

It seems that the Body fragment is not needed

@YitzhakKhabinsky I am afraid I have no idea what you want from me. Did you run my code with OP's input? If so, how is the output different from the output specified in the question? If you did not, why are you wasting my time with these comments?

@y.arazim.. Thank you very much. This solved my problem.

Here's another suggestion that produces an output which is semantically but not lexically the same as your desired output.
The elements in the new document are renamed to use the namespace URI http://www.tutorialspoint.com, except those that were descendants of the Message element, which are renamed to use the urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:header.001.001.04 namespace URI. In both cases the namespace URI is used as the default namespace (i.e. it used unprefixed in the names of the elements). Incidentally this produces the smallest serialization of the desired element names.
A separate template matching the Body element is used to discard that element.
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:main="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0"
exclude-result-prefixes="main">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::main:Message]">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:header.001.001.04">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.tutorialspoint.com">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="main:Body"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Result:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataPDU xmlns="http://www.tutorialspoint.com">
   <Revision>2.0.10</Revision>
   <Header>
      <Message xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:header.001.001.04">
         <SenderReference>112712406</SenderReference>
         <MessageIdentifier>pacs.008.001.08</MessageIdentifier>
         <Format>MX</Format>
         <SubFormat>Input</SubFormat>
         <Sender>
            <DN>ou=xxx,o=ctbaau2s,o=swift</DN>
            <FullName>
               <X1>CTBAAU2SFXD</X1>
            </FullName>
         </Sender>
         <Receiver>
            <DN>ou=xxx,o=testcsns,o=swift</DN>
            <FullName>
               <X1>TESTCSNSSFXXX</X1>
            </FullName>
         </Receiver>
         <InterfaceInfo>
            <UserReference>M13782445</UserReference>
         </InterfaceInfo>
         <NetworkInfo>
            <SWIFTNetNetworkInfo>
               <RequestType>pacs.008.001.08</RequestType>
               <RequestSubtype>swift.cbprplus.02</RequestSubtype>
            </SWIFTNetNetworkInfo>
         </NetworkInfo>
      </Message>
   </Header>
</DataPDU>


Thank you very much. This solved my problem.
